# XmppClientConnection OnLogin event never firing after OnIq

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmpp, agsxmpp

Here's my setup:

```
Jid jid = new Jid ( "*******@jabber.ua" );
XmppClientConnection connection = new XmppClientConnection ( jid.Server );
connection.Open ( jid.User, "**********" );
```

After calling **connection.Open**, everything is working nicely, i.e. **connection.XmppConnectionState** is changing from *Connecting* to *Connected* to *Securing* to *Authenticating* to *Authenticated* to *Binding*. Between **connection.XmppConnectionState** becoming *Securing* and *Authenticating* there's an **ArgumentNullException** thrown in **mscorlib.dll** according to output, but it shows nowhere else. After **connection.XmppConnectionState** hitting *Binding*, the following exchange happens:

```
<iq id="agsXMPP_1" 
    type="set" 
    to="jabber.ua">
    <bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind">
        <resource>agsXMPP</resource>
    </bind>
</iq>

<iq xmlns="jabber:client" 
    id="agsXMPP_1" 
    type="error" 
    from="jabber.ua">
    <error type="cancel">
        <service-unavailable xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas" />
    </error>
</iq>
```

And after  being passed into **connection.OnIq** event, everything stops happening, i.e. no XmppClientConnection events firing, no exceptions raised, nothing at all happens until closing the connection.

Comment: please post the complete Xml log. But it looks like your server replies aith an error to the bind Iq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks like you run a Prosody server. Prosody returns this error when the BindIq gets sent with a to attribute. This problem was fixed a while ago in agsXMPP. Please use the latest code from the source repository.

Comment: Could you please point me to correct repository? The version I've used pretty much could be outdated, as I've simply used what was available through NuGet.

Comment: You can find the subversion repo here on this page:
http://www.ag-software.net/agsxmpp-sdk/download/